# Data Retention on VIewController/Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

Had a quick question:

I have 2 view controllers, and their associated views.

The first VC have images which have been coloured through masking. [This is a link](http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage) to the technique I will be employing.

The second VC and view is simply a settings screen that will hold random content.

Assume this scenario:

1. First VC with images is loaded up and the coloring is completed

   NOTE: Coloring is random and the value is not stored anywhere.  With
   so many images it would be difficult to store all those random
   colors in variables.
2. On the First VC the user presses the button navigating to the
   setting screen
3. the Second VC is now loaded, via a Modal operation
4. On the Second VC the user presses a "back" button to return to
   the previous VC, which in this case is the First VC.

The question: During navigation and after the the navigation back to the First VC will the images and colors I randomly and programmatically chose still be visible or will I lose those randomly generated colors? If not how do I ensure that what has been rendered on the First VC will be maintained throughout any navigation operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the View Controller stays on the navigation stack, all of the data it holds will still be valid when you return to it. Pushing any number of View Controllers on top of the stack will do nothing to the first view controller, but as soon as you pop the first one off of the stack, it will lose any data it had unless saved otherwise and reloaded(in a variable in the App Delegate, for example).

Comment: What if I am not using a navigation controller? I just have VC, they are all navigated through buttons, there are not Navigation Controllers involved.

Comment: In that case, you're not really navigating back to the original view. That being said, you mentioned the second view is modal, as well. A modal view controller "pops up" above the view controller that calls it, and with modal view controllers being what they are, the original view controller would stay in memory under it, because the first view controller is there, it's just "under" the modal view until it is dismissed. That being said, any navigation is best done with a navigation controller and the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

You will not loose the images you created unless you release the first view. Since you are showing the second view on top of first view, all the images will be there. You dont have to worry about saving the colors or images. You can push any number of view controllers on top of this first view controller.

Note that this is valid only if you are not removing/popping/dismissing the first view controller or its view.

Comment: Isn't navigating away or switching to a different VC releasing the first view?

Comment: No, it is not. It will remain in the stack. Basically it is retained until the view controller is removed from stack. Whenever you are pushing a viewcontroller, it gets retained and when you are popping out, it will be released.